# PHP use full path from root to link to file instead of going from parent

Tags: php, html

I need to be able to access a file in a folder located in the root directory on each of my pages.

Is there a piece of code I can use to type out the full directory going from the root folder to the specific folder I want and be able to copy onto each page without having to change the code?

For more clarification, it's hard to word, but I want to be able to link top my CSS file in the directory /css on each page without manually having to put ../../ etc.

Or does anyone else know the best way to link one style sheet to each page with ease?

Comment: Did you try to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Comment: I did, but despite working in another bit of code, it tried to load /c://users/tom/... if you get my jist. Not sure what happened, but it was perfect code. Is it true I can just do a "/" before the directory in basic HTML to get back to the root folder?

Comment: No you have to put "../"

Comment: Are you talking about _server-side_ or _client-side_ path here? Form your comment, I think it might be the latter. Then you can simply prefix your relative path with a leading slash `/` – the browser will complete that using the current protocol and domain.

Comment: [Relative and absolute paths](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html) a little guide about this

Comment: I went with the "/" starting for the link to the CSS file, which worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root of your website has the path `/` (in other words, the address you type for the root of your website is something like `http://mydomain.com/`) then you can simply refer to your CSS files using `/my.css` or `/css/my.css` in all pages. The leading `/` tells the browser to look for these files relative to the root of your website.

Comment: AHA! That's the one. I never realised this was actually a thing, despite studying HTML since I was 10... Oh dear. This seems to have solved everything

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a relative path of /folder path that will be accessible from all your pages.

You should also be able to do it the same was Cristian is recommending with:

```
    $folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder path";
```

Comment: Unfortunatley I couldn't get that to work. Although this is a different way of doing it, it will be handy in the future, so thanks for your answer :)